# converting web server logs (apache,iis, etc..) to relational Database

Tags: sql, database, webserver

i have some apache logs and i want to be able to query the data in it.
so i wanted to know if its possible to convert this log data to a relational database so i later can query and analyze the data using sql statments.
thanks

Comment: Possibility of converting them to a sqlite3 file would be nice as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Log Parser](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1287) by Microsoft will let you query various types of data with SQL without needing to convert it.

> Log parser is a powerful, versatile
>   tool that provides universal query
>   access to text-based data such as log
>   files, XML files and CSV files, as
>   well as key data sources on the
>   Windows® operating system such as the
>   Event Log, the Registry, the file
>   system, and Active Directory®. You
>   tell Log Parser what information you
>   need and how you want it processed.
>   The results of your query can be
>   custom-formatted in text based output,
>   or they can be persisted to more
>   specialty targets like SQL, SYSLOG, or
>   a chart.

Comment: I think you can also get it to write to a relational database as well - probably better from a performance point of view if you have a large number of logs.